# What causes unrelated data load errors after modifying unrelated code in opentaps/ofbiz?

Tags: crm, ofbiz

I get the following build errors after a 'run-install' command:

```
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,323 (main) [EntityDataLoadContainer.java:406:INFO ] 00008 of 18145 from file:/Users/lanre/Projects/crm_remote_local/opentaps/amazon/data/AmazonDemoSetup.xml
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,323 (main) [EntityDataLoadContainer.java:406:INFO ] 00013 of 18158 from file:/Users/lanre/Projects/crm_remote_local/opentaps/amazon/data/AmazonDemoData.xml
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,323 (main) [EntityDataLoadContainer.java:411:INFO ] The following errors occured in the data load:
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,323 (main) [EntityDataLoadContainer.java:413:INFO ] [install.loadData]: Error loading XML Resource "file:/Users/lanre/Projects/crm_remote_local/opentaps/opentaps-common/data/TaxAuthorities_US.xml"; Error was: A transaction error occurred reading data
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,324 (main) [EntityDataLoadContainer.java:413:INFO ] [install.loadData]: Error loading XML Resource "file:/Users/lanre/Projects/crm_remote_local/applications/content/data/DemoBlogUsersData.xml"; Error was: A transaction error occurred reading data
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,324 (main) [EntityDataLoadContainer.java:413:INFO ] [install.loadData]: Error loading XML Resource "file:/Users/lanre/Projects/crm_remote_local/applications/accounting/data/DemoOrganizationData.xml"; Error was: A transaction error occurred reading data
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,324 (main) [EntityDataLoadContainer.java:413:INFO ] [install.loadData]: Error loading XML Resource "file:/Users/lanre/Projects/crm_remote_local/applications/accounting/data/DemoTaxAuthority.xml"; Error was: A transaction error occurred reading data
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,324 (main) [EntityDataLoadContainer.java:413:INFO ] [install.loadData]: Error loading XML Resource "file:/Users/lanre/Projects/crm_remote_local/applications/order/data/OrderDemoData.xml"; Error was: A transaction error occurred reading data
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,324 (main) [EntityDataLoadContainer.java:413:INFO ] [install.loadData]: Error loading XML Resource "file:/Users/lanre/Projects/crm_remote_local/applications/order/data/SalesOrderDemoData.xml"; Error was: A transaction error occurred reading data
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,324 (main) [EntityDataLoadContainer.java:413:INFO ] [install.loadData]: Error loading XML Resource "file:/Users/lanre/Projects/crm_remote_local/applications/marketing/data/sfaDemoData.xml"; Error was: A transaction error occurred reading data
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,324 (main) [EntityDataLoadContainer.java:413:INFO ] [install.loadData]: Error loading XML Resource "file:/Users/lanre/Projects/crm_remote_local/specialpurpose/ecommerce/data/DemoProduct.xml"; Error was: A transaction error occurred reading data
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,324 (main) [EntityDataLoadContainer.java:413:INFO ] [install.loadData]: Error loading XML Resource "file:/Users/lanre/Projects/crm_remote_local/specialpurpose/ecommerce/data/DemoOrderTestData.xml"; Error was: A transaction error occurred reading data
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,324 (main) [EntityDataLoadContainer.java:413:INFO ] [install.loadData]: Error loading XML Resource "file:/Users/lanre/Projects/crm_remote_local/specialpurpose/projectmgr/data/ProjectMgrDemoData.xml"; Error was: A transaction error occurred reading data
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,324 (main) [EntityDataLoadContainer.java:413:INFO ] [install.loadData]: Error loading XML Resource "file:/Users/lanre/Projects/crm_remote_local/opentaps/crmsfa/data/CRMSFADemoData.xml"; Error was: A transaction error occurred reading data
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,324 (main) [EntityDataLoadContainer.java:413:INFO ] [install.loadData]: Error loading XML Resource "file:/Users/lanre/Projects/crm_remote_local/opentaps/crmsfa/data/CRMSFADemoChartData.xml"; Error was: A transaction error occurred reading data
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,324 (main) [EntityDataLoadContainer.java:413:INFO ] [install.loadData]: Error loading XML Resource "file:/Users/lanre/Projects/crm_remote_local/opentaps/financials/data/DemoLockbox.xml"; Error was: A transaction error occurred reading data
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,325 (main) [EntityDataLoadContainer.java:413:INFO ] [install.loadData]: Error loading XML Resource "file:/Users/lanre/Projects/crm_remote_local/opentaps/opentaps-tests/data/crmsfa/OrderTestData.xml"; Error was: A transaction error occurred reading data
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,325 (main) [EntityDataLoadContainer.java:413:INFO ] [install.loadData]: Error loading XML Resource "file:/Users/lanre/Projects/crm_remote_local/opentaps/opentaps-tests/data/purchasing/OrderTestData.xml"; Error was: A transaction error occurred reading data
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,325 (main) [EntityDataLoadContainer.java:417:INFO ] =-=-=-=-=-=-= Finished the data load with 18158 rows changed.
     [java] org.ofbiz.base.start.StartupException: Cannot start() org.ofbiz.entityext.data.EntityDataLoadContainer (Errors occurred during the data load.)
     [java]     at org.ofbiz.base.container.ContainerLoader.start(ContainerLoader.java:103)
     [java]     at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.startStartLoaders(Start.java:273)
     [java]     at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.startServer(Start.java:323)
     [java]     at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.start(Start.java:327)
     [java]     at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.main(Start.java:412)
     [java] org.ofbiz.base.container.ContainerException: Errors occurred during the data load.
     [java]     at org.ofbiz.entityext.data.EntityDataLoadContainer.start(EntityDataLoadContainer.java:420)
     [java]     at org.ofbiz.base.container.ContainerLoader.start(ContainerLoader.java:101)
     [java]     at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.startStartLoaders(Start.java:273)
     [java]     at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.startServer(Start.java:323)
     [java]     at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.start(Start.java:327)
     [java]     at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.main(Start.java:412)
     [java] org.ofbiz.base.container.ContainerException: Errors occurred during the data load.
     [java]     at org.ofbiz.entityext.data.EntityDataLoadContainer.start(EntityDataLoadContainer.java:420)
     [java]     at org.ofbiz.base.container.ContainerLoader.start(ContainerLoader.java:101)
     [java]     at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.startStartLoaders(Start.java:273)
     [java]     at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.startServer(Start.java:323)
     [java]     at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.start(Start.java:327)
     [java]     at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.main(Start.java:412)
     [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:19,327 (OFBiz_Shutdown_Hook) [    ContainerLoader.java:114:INFO ] Shutting down containers

BUILD FAILED
/Users/lanre/Projects/crm_remote_local/build.xml:510: Java returned: 99
```

This is something that seems to happen a lot when changing unrelated parts of opentaps. I don't understand why after, for instance, changing something in java code the subsequent re-builds cause these data loading errors. One other things is that these errors were preceded by a few of the following kind of errors much earlier on in the console output:

```
[java] 2013-03-05 17:04:17,882 (main) [  ServiceDispatcher.java:516:INFO ] [[Sync service failed...- total:0.0,since last(Begin):0.0]] - 'entity-default / recalcInvoiceAmounts'
 [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:17,882 (main) [    TransactionUtil.java:371:WARN ] 
 [java] ---- exception report ----------------------------------------------------------
 [java] [TransactionUtil.setRollbackOnly] Calling transaction setRollbackOnly; this stack trace shows where this is happening:
 [java] Exception: java.lang.Exception
 [java] Message: Service [recalcInvoiceAmounts] threw an unexpected exception/error
 [java] ---- stack trace ---------------------------------------------------------------
 [java] java.lang.Exception: Service [recalcInvoiceAmounts] threw an unexpected exception/error
 [java] org.ofbiz.entity.transaction.TransactionUtil.setRollbackOnly(TransactionUtil.java:371)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entity.transaction.TransactionUtil.rollback(TransactionUtil.java:313)
 [java] org.ofbiz.service.ServiceDispatcher.runSync(ServiceDispatcher.java:525)
 [java] org.ofbiz.service.ServiceDispatcher.runSync(ServiceDispatcher.java:227)
 [java] org.ofbiz.service.GenericDispatcher.runSync(GenericDispatcher.java:166)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entityext.eca.EntityEcaAction.runAction(EntityEcaAction.java:93)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entityext.eca.EntityEcaRule.eval(EntityEcaRule.java:121)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entityext.eca.DelegatorEcaHandler.aw$original$_AW_$evalRules$_AW_$org_ofbiz_entityext_eca_DelegatorEcaHandler(DelegatorEcaHandler.java:86)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entityext.eca.DelegatorEcaHandler_1_1999504294_1997194061___AW_JoinPoint.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entityext.eca.DelegatorEcaHandler.evalRules(DelegatorEcaHandler.java)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entity.GenericDelegator$EntityEcaRuleRunner.evalRules(GenericDelegator.java:2874)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entity.GenericDelegator.store(GenericDelegator.java:1364)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entity.GenericDelegator.storeAll(GenericDelegator.java:1459)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entity.util.EntitySaxReader.writeValues(EntitySaxReader.java:286)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entity.util.EntitySaxReader.parse(EntitySaxReader.java:265)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entity.util.EntitySaxReader.parse(EntitySaxReader.java:222)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entity.util.EntityDataLoader.loadData(EntityDataLoader.java:214)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entityext.data.EntityDataLoadContainer.start(EntityDataLoadContainer.java:389)
 [java] org.ofbiz.base.container.ContainerLoader.start(ContainerLoader.java:101)
 [java] org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.startStartLoaders(Start.java:273)
 [java] org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.startServer(Start.java:323)
 [java] org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.start(Start.java:327)
 [java] org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.main(Start.java:412)
 [java] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [java] 
 [java] 2013-03-05 17:04:17,883 (main) [    EntityEcaAction.java:111:ERROR] 
 [java] ---- exception report ----------------------------------------------------------
 [java] Error running Entity ECA action service
 [java] Exception: org.ofbiz.service.GenericServiceException
 [java] Message: Error or unknown exception (org/opentaps/base/services/RecalcInvoiceAmountsService : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0)
 [java] ---- cause ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 [java] Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError
 [java] Message: org/opentaps/base/services/RecalcInvoiceAmountsService : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
 [java] ---- stack trace ---------------------------------------------------------------
 [java] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/opentaps/base/services/RecalcInvoiceAmountsService : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
 [java] java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 [java] java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
 [java] java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
 [java] java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
 [java] java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
 [java] java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
 [java] java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
 [java] java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java] java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 [java] java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 [java] java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 [java] java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 [java] java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2398)
 [java] java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2708)
 [java] java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:328)
 [java] java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
 [java] org.opentaps.foundation.service.ofbiz.POJOJavaEngine.serviceInvoker(POJOJavaEngine.java:170)
 [java] org.opentaps.foundation.service.ofbiz.POJOJavaEngine.runSync(POJOJavaEngine.java:117)
 [java] org.ofbiz.service.ModelServiceReader$GenericInvokerImpl.runSync(ModelServiceReader.java:762)
 [java] _$gen.file_58$.Users.lanre.Projects.crm_95$remote_95$local.opentaps.financials.servicedef.services_95$invoice_46$xml_35$recalcInvoiceAmounts.runSync(file:/Users/lanre/Projects/crm_remote_local/opentaps/financials/servicedef/services_invoice.xml#recalcInvoiceAmounts:359)
 [java] org.ofbiz.service.ServiceDispatcher.runSync(ServiceDispatcher.java:400)
 [java] org.ofbiz.service.ServiceDispatcher.runSync(ServiceDispatcher.java:227)
 [java] org.ofbiz.service.GenericDispatcher.runSync(GenericDispatcher.java:166)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entityext.eca.EntityEcaAction.runAction(EntityEcaAction.java:93)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entityext.eca.EntityEcaRule.eval(EntityEcaRule.java:121)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entityext.eca.DelegatorEcaHandler.aw$original$_AW_$evalRules$_AW_$org_ofbiz_entityext_eca_DelegatorEcaHandler(DelegatorEcaHandler.java:86)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entityext.eca.DelegatorEcaHandler_1_1999504294_1997194061___AW_JoinPoint.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entityext.eca.DelegatorEcaHandler.evalRules(DelegatorEcaHandler.java)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entity.GenericDelegator$EntityEcaRuleRunner.evalRules(GenericDelegator.java:2874)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entity.GenericDelegator.store(GenericDelegator.java:1364)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entity.GenericDelegator.storeAll(GenericDelegator.java:1459)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entity.util.EntitySaxReader.writeValues(EntitySaxReader.java:286)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entity.util.EntitySaxReader.parse(EntitySaxReader.java:265)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entity.util.EntitySaxReader.parse(EntitySaxReader.java:222)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entity.util.EntityDataLoader.loadData(EntityDataLoader.java:214)
 [java] org.ofbiz.entityext.data.EntityDataLoadContainer.start(EntityDataLoadContainer.java:389)
 [java] org.ofbiz.base.container.ContainerLoader.start(ContainerLoader.java:101)
 [java] org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.startStartLoaders(Start.java:273)
 [java] org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.startServer(Start.java:323)
 [java] org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.start(Start.java:327)
 [java] org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.main(Start.java:412)
```

I'm on Ofbiz/opentaps 10.04/1.5 respectively using JDK 1.7 on OSX 10.7.x

Answer (score 0):

Please note that opentaps does not support jdk 1.7 please use .1.6

Comment: I actually did which also never solved the problem. Weird thing is the opentaps would still start despite the build failure, also however after one of my numerous 'run-install' rebuild it just went away.